# json response from database in android

Tags: android

Hi In this code the data is coming from json response and all the values are coming correctly.But while debugging it's showing null pointer exception  but it's showing this error can any one please help me

**Logcat**

```
11-06 06:31:28.564: E/Fail 3(1169): java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
11-06 06:31:28.564: W/System.err(1169): java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null
11-06 06:31:28.564: W/System.err(1169):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
11-06 06:31:28.574: W/System.err(1169):     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:154)
11-06 06:31:28.574: W/System.err(1169):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
11-06 06:31:28.574: W/System.err(1169):     at com.example.vcarehospital.IPD_Registration.spinner_fn(IPD_Registration.java:442)
11-06 06:31:28.574: W/System.err(1169):     at com.example.vcarehospital.IPD_Registration.onCreate(IPD_Registration.java:316)
11-06 06:31:28.584: W/System.err(1169):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-06 06:31:28.584: W/System.err(1169):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-06 06:31:28.584: W/System.err(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-06 06:31:28.584: W/System.err(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-06 06:31:28.594: W/System.err(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-06 06:31:28.594: W/System.err(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-06 06:31:28.594: W/System.err(1169):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 06:31:28.604: W/System.err(1169):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 06:31:28.604: W/System.err(1169):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-06 06:31:28.604: W/System.err(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 06:31:28.614: W/System.err(1169):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 06:31:28.614: W/System.err(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-06 06:31:28.614: W/System.err(1169):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-06 06:31:28.624: W/System.err(1169):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**java class**

```
String department = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("Department","");
   System.out.print(department);

   try
   {
    JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(department);
    department_id = new String[JA.length()];
    department_name = new String[JA.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<JA.length();i++)
    {
        department_id[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("department_id");
        department_name[i] = JA.getJSONObject(i).getString("department_name");
      departMap.put(department_name[i],department_id[i]);
    }

     spinner_fn();


   }


   catch(Exception e)
   {
       Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: please show the entire stacktrace. which of those lines triggers the exception?

Comment: This particular exception  is thrown when the array parameter passed to ArrayAdapter is null. Could you post the code for the spinner_fn() method? Also, if your json string is not correct, JSONArray(department) will not produce a proper JSONArray.

Comment: IPD_Registration.java line no. 442 : post the line its pointing to or rather post this class too.